# Jquery Content Carousel not loading items properly

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I am working on simple bootstrap content carousel....
[Live Demo](http://euroaz.tv/Home/loadEpisodes/7?epId=0&name=Mr-Bean-Cizgi-serial%C4%B1)

The problem is that there should load 3 items each slide.....as can be seen from code but there loads only one item on each slide....The rest of the slider is working good except the item loading...

**Razor Code :**

```
<div class="container img-responsive" style="background: #d9e5e9;
padding-left: -0px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-top: 10px;
margin: 20px auto; width: 980px;">
    <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            @{
                int counter = 0;
                foreach (var item in ViewBag.LoadEps)
                {
                    if (counter == 0)
                    {
                        <div class="item active">
                            <div class="col-lg-4">   
   <a href="@Url.Action("LoadEpisodes", "Home", new { id = item.VideoId,
    epId =item.VideoEpisodeId, name = item.Title.Replace(" ", "-")}, null)"
    style="color: white; text-align: center; line-height: 12px;">
    <img src="@Url.Content(item.PosterUrl)" height="130" 
    width="200" alt="@item.Title" class="ImageBorder" /><br />@item.Title
                                    </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        <div class="item">
                            <div class="col-lg-4">
                               
    <a href="@Url.Action("LoadEpisodes", "Home", new { id = item.VideoId,
    epId =item.VideoEpisodeId, name = item.Title.Replace(" ", "-")}, null)"
    style="color: white; text-align: center; line-height: 12px;">
    <img src="@Url.Content(item.PosterUrl)" height="130" 
    width="200" alt="@item.Title" class="ImageBorder" /><br />@item.Title
                                    </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        </div>
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Style**

```
<style>
    .carousel-inner .active.left {
        left: -25%;
    }

    .carousel-inner .next {
        left: 25%;
    }

    .carousel-inner .prev {
        left: -25%;
    }

    .carousel-control {
        width: 4%;
    }

        .carousel-control.left, .carousel-control.right {
            margin-left: 15px;
            background-color: #036ca6;
        }
</style>
```

**Script**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myCarousel').carousel({
            interval: 4000
        })

        $('.carousel .item').each(function () {
            var next = $(this).next();
            if (!next.length) {
                next = $(this).siblings(':first');
            }
            next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

            for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                next = next.next();
                if (!next.length) {
                    next = $(this).siblings(':first');
                }

                next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The problem only with the items loading, although slider is working fine, libraries loading fine....
I have no idea how to test it and find error like console errors in firebug...
I wasn't able to sort out the jquery by myself....
If some one please any type of help will be appreciated.....
Thanks for your time..

Comment: I think the carousel is only good for 1 item, if you want more the term is slider.

Comment: thanks for reply, how can i arrange that http://www.bootply.com/89193....it already failed to work with foreach loop

Comment: How do you want to arrange it?

Comment: Again, this is a carousel and so, AS FAR AS I KNOW, there are no options there for number of items that appear. Do you just want to create a slider that is working with Bootstrap framework?

Comment: i just want to load 3 items each, and sliding one item at time, is it possible???

Comment: Sure, one moment please.

Comment: yes i have tried several jquery sliders but they didn't work, so i turned to bootstrap

Comment: OWL Carousel works best in regular websites and inside wordpress in my experience, it is extremely easy to setup and use: http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/ - I will create an example for you.

Comment: no i have tried owl carousel before it will not work in my project

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78280/discussion-between-odedta-and-suhail-mumtaz-awan).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working example of OWL carousel which works fine anywhere I've tried, if it doesn't work for you, hop on chat and i'll help you get it working.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cjz6La1x/)

```
<div id="owl-example" class="owl-carousel">
    <div> <img src="http://cdn.oxwordsblog.wpfuel.co.uk/wpcms/wp-content/uploads/Lion_iStock_XSmall-300x300.jpg?24a0bc" /> </div>
  <div> <img src="http://www.wildlife-pictures-online.com/image-files/lion-male_2724.jpg" /> </div>
  <div> <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/94/Lion_Foret.jpg" /> </div>
    <div> <img src="http://cdn.oxwordsblog.wpfuel.co.uk/wpcms/wp-content/uploads/Lion_iStock_XSmall-300x300.jpg?24a0bc" /> </div>
  <div> <img src="http://www.wildlife-pictures-online.com/image-files/lion-male_2724.jpg" /> </div>
  <div> <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/94/Lion_Foret.jpg" /> </div>
    <div> <img src="http://cdn.oxwordsblog.wpfuel.co.uk/wpcms/wp-content/uploads/Lion_iStock_XSmall-300x300.jpg?24a0bc" /> </div>
  <div> <img src="http://www.wildlife-pictures-online.com/image-files/lion-male_2724.jpg" /> </div>
  <div> <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/94/Lion_Foret.jpg" /> </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#owl-example").owlCarousel({
        autoPlay: 3000, //Set AutoPlay to 3 seconds
        items : 3,   
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. my **solution**: ok if i have 8 image loaded in DOM and then using jquery if you set `items: 7`  it will work, but if i set  `items: 8` or  `items: 10` it wont work.

Comment: @stom the `items` attribute means this: `This variable allows you to set the maximum amount of items displayed at a time with the widest browser width` - that means that if you have 8 images in the DOM, all of them will be loaded as the "first slide".